# Using a regular expression as the name of a function or variable

Tags: regex, function

I'm trying to find a way to use [a regular expression] as a [variable name] or [a function name]. Do any programming or scripting languages offer this feature?

Example of the feature I want (using Java-like pseudocode):

```
int <<(my|a|an)(number|Integer)>> = 10;
//this variable has a regular expression as a name

function <<((print|write)(Stuff|Things|Words))>>(int myInt){
//this function has a regular expression as a name
     System.out.println(myInt);
}

printStuff(myInt); //should have the same effect as the next line
writeWords(anInteger); //should have the same effect as the previous line
```

Comment: Why?  There must be a better way to solve whatever real problem you're after this to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to make it possible to refer to a function or variable by more than one name so that I won't need to memorize the exact name of a function with a long name. Typing a string that matches the regular expression (convert|change)((int|integer)Array)(To)(DoubleArray|arrayOfDoubles) and making that regular expression refer to a specific function is easier than trying to remember the exact name of the function.

Comment: I could also set up some kind of macro to automatically replace text in the source code that I'm working with. That might be a better solution.

Comment: @AndersonGreen: That's not a great idea, because then you'll never be able to find the function you're calling. If you can't remember exactly what `convertIntArrayToDoubleArray` is called, then how will you remember exactly what it does? (Does it take an integer array and return a double array? Does it take an integer array to read from and a double array to write to -- and if so, which argument comes first? Does it just take an array of integers and change its elements to doubles, in-place? Though that last one, admittedly, is unlikely in Java.)

Comment: If it's a limited number of names, it's probably better to create aliases for them then using some regex trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Perl you could do such things for functions using [`AUTOLOAD`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Autoloading).

[Example](http://ideone.com/5G6Ew):

```
my @refun = (
        [qr/(print|write)(Stuff|Things|Words)/ => sub { print "printStuff(@_)\n"; }],
        [qr/fo+(?:ba+r)?/ => sub { print "foobar(@_)\n"; }],
        );

our $AUTOLOAD;
sub AUTOLOAD{
        for(@refun){
                my ($re, $sub) = @$_;
                goto &$sub if $AUTOLOAD =~ /$re/;
        }

        my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
        die "Undefined subroutine &$AUTOLOAD called at $filename line $line.\n";
}


printStuff(10);
writeWords(10);
foo();
fooooooooooooooobar(1,2,3);
```

Output:

```
printStuff(10)
printStuff(10)
foobar()
foobar(1 2 3)
```

Not sure about variables, but it's probably possible as well.

Comment: I'm quite impressed to see an answer to this question. This is probably the most bizarre and esoteric question I've ever posted here, and you still managed to answer it. :)